# How to get the name of the current kde activity?

Tags: plasma, kde-activities

How to print the name of the current kde activity alone?
The activity bar displays all activities, highlighting the current one.
I would find useful an unobtrusive widget to print the current activity name only.

thank you

p.

Comment: Welcome on U&L! Are you looking for a way to get the Activity name programmatically, e.g. for using it in a script? Or for a way to see the current Activity's name somewhere in the desktop area? Please, [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/643331/edit) this information into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using a widget (verbose instructions for future readers):

In Plasma Desktop's default panel (the bar at the bottom of the desktop), right-click on a free area and select "Add Widgets"; in the Widgets panel, search for "Activities"; drag the Activities widget to the panel. It is a relatively unobtrusive widget that shows the name of the current activity and opens the activity manager when clicked on.

Using D-Bus (noting that the question's [first revision](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/643331/1) explicitly mentioned it):

```bsh
CurrentActivity=$(dbus-send --session --dest=org.kde.ActivityManager \
  --type=method_call --print-reply=literal /ActivityManager/Activities \
  org.kde.ActivityManager.Activities.CurrentActivity | tr -d "[:blank:]")

dbus-send --session --dest=org.kde.ActivityManager --type=method_call \
  --print-reply /ActivityManager/Activities \
  org.kde.ActivityManager.Activities.ActivityInformation \
  "string:$CurrentActivity"
```

You may want to use `-print-reply=literal` instead of `-print-reply` to reduce the amount of output. It can then be filtered, piping it through something like `awk 'NR==2 {print $2}'` to get the current activity's name only. Note, though, that activity names can include white spaces, tabs and double quotes, making `dbus-send`'s output hard, if not impossible, to parse reliably in the general case.